# How to iterate multilevel dataframe in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

There are json values inside my dataframe now i want to iterate them i have tried several ways but i am failed . I have tried to convert the dataframe values into nested dictionary so that they can be easily iteratable but i am also failed

**After iterating the values I want to save again insdie the dataframe in the expanded form so that i can get all the values**

this is some how my dictionary values

```
{
  ('1144986',
  '1'): {
    'batsmen': [
      {
        'name': 'NM Coulter-Nile',
        'stats': {
          'runs': {
            'name': 'runs',
            'text': 'RUNS',
            'value': '34'
          },
          'ballsFaced': {
            'name': 'ballsFaced',
            'text': 'BF',
            'value': '31'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        'name': 'AT Carey',
        'stats': {
          'runs': {
            'name': 'runs',
            'text': 'RUNS',
            'value': '33'
          },
          'ballsFaced': {
            'name': 'ballsFaced',
            'text': 'BF',
            'value': '71'
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    'bowlers': [
      {
        'name': 'DW Steyn',
        'stats': {
          'overs': {
            'name': 'overs',
            'text': 'O',
            'value': '7'
          },
          'wickets': {
            'name': 'wickets',
            'text': 'E',
            'value': '2'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        'name': 'AL Phehlukwayo',
        'stats': {
          'overs': {
            'name': 'overs',
            'text': 'O',
            'value': '6'
          },
          'wickets': {
            'name': 'wickets',
            'text': 'E',
            'value': '3'
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    'team': {
      'teamDisplayName': 'AUSTRALIA',
      'innDisplayName': 'INNINGS',
      'runs': 152,
      'overs': 38.1,
      'wickets': 10,
      'description': 'all out',
      'inningsRunWicket': 152,
      'inningStatus': ''
    }
  },
  ('1144986',
  '2'): {
    'batsmen': [
      {
        'name': 'RR Hendricks',
        'stats': {
          'runs': {
            'name': 'runs',
            'text': 'RUNS',
            'value': '44'
          },
          'ballsFaced': {
            'name': 'ballsFaced',
            'text': 'BF',
            'value': '74'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        'name': 'Q de Kock',
        'stats': {
          'runs': {
            'name': 'runs',
            'text': 'RUNS',
            'value': '47'
          },
          'ballsFaced': {
            'name': 'ballsFaced',
            'text': 'BF',
            'value': '40'
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    'bowlers': [
      {
        'name': 'NM Coulter-Nile',
        'stats': {
          'overs': {
            'name': 'overs',
            'text': 'O',
            'value': '3'
          },
          'wickets': {
            'name': 'wickets',
            'text': 'E',
            'value': '1'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        'name': 'MP Stoinis',
        'stats': {
          'overs': {
            'name': 'overs',
            'text': 'O',
            'value': '4.2'
          },
          'wickets': {
            'name': 'wickets',
            'text': 'E',
            'value': '3'
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    'team': {
      'teamDisplayName': 'SOUTH AFRICA',
      'innDisplayName': 'INNINGS',
      'runs': 153,
      'overs': 29.2,
      'wickets': 4,
      'description': 'target reached',
      'inningsRunWicket': '153/4',
      'inningStatus': ''
    }
  }
}
```

**If anyone can help with dataframe he can also do that i am also pasting an image for reference of the dataframe.**

this is some how my dataframe

[image]

**I just want to iterate through the json values whether it is from dictionary or whether it is from data frame**

Comment: ` a = json.load("json_name")` have you tried this

Comment: @RahulAgarwal i want to iterate and then save inside the dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, your json is not valid because `{('1144986','1'): 'whatever'}` isn't a valid json, instead it's an extremely convoluted python dictionary definition containing lists and other dictionaries which, luckily, pandas can handle but not in a graceful manner I'm afraid.

Now watch the magic (sorry for the images, textual representation is not informative):

```
js_dict = {('1144986','1'):{'batsmen'  ... # this line won't execute, just for completeness

# Get the initial dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(js_dict, orient='index')
```

which is going to look like
[image]

Now, let's take care of teams, batsmen and bowlers.

---

**Team**

```
teams = pd.concat(df['team'].apply(pd.DataFrame.from_dict, orient='index')
                  .apply(lambda x: x.T)
                  .to_dict()).reset_index(level=2,drop=True)
```

[image]

```
# Join back to the initial dataframe
df = df.join(teams).drop('team', axis=1)
```

---

**Batsmen**

```
batsmen = pd.concat(df['batsmen']
                .apply(pd.DataFrame)
                .to_dict()).reset_index(level=2,drop=True)
```

[image]

```
# Join with the initial dataframe renaming some columns in the process
batsmen = batsmen.join(df).drop(['batsmen', 'bowlers'], axis=1)
batsmen = batsmen.rename(columns={'name': 'batsman_name',
                              'stats': 'batsman_stats'})
```

**Stats**

```
batsman_stats = pd.concat(batsmen['batsman_stats']
                          .apply(pd.DataFrame)
                          .apply(lambda x: x.T).to_dict()).reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
```

```
# Join back with some renamings
batsmen = batsman_stats.join(batsmen).drop('batsman_stats', axis=1)
batsmen = batsmen.rename(columns={'name': 'batsman_stats_name',
                                  'text': 'batsman_stats_text',
                                  'value': 'batsman_stats_value'})
```

[image]

---

**Bowlers**

```
bowlers = pd.concat(df['bowlers']
                .apply(pd.DataFrame)
                .to_dict()).reset_index(level=2,drop=True)
```

```
# Join with the initial dataframe renaming some columns in the process
bowlers = bowlers.join(df).drop(['batsmen', 'bowlers'], axis=1)
bowlers = bowlers.rename(columns={'name': 'bowler_name',
                                  'stats': 'bowler_stats'})
```

[image]

**Stats**

```
bowler_stats = pd.concat(df['bowler_stats']
                         .apply(pd.DataFrame)
                         .apply(lambda x: x.T)
                         .to_dict()).reset_index(level=2, drop=True)

# Merge back and rename
bowlers = bowler_stats.join(bowlers).drop('bowler_stats', axis=1)
bowlers = bowlers.rename(columns={'name': 'bowler_stats_name',
                        'text': 'bowler_stats_text',
                        'value': 'bowler_stats_value'})
```

[image]

Comment: i have tried the solution but i am having error in
batsmen = batsmen.join(batsmen).drop(['batsmen', 'bowlers'], axis=1)
its overlapping column

Comment: Hmm, can you please refresh the page maybe because the latest version of my answer has `batsmen = batsmen.join(df).drop(['batsmen', 'bowlers'], axis=1)`?

Comment: let me try with this